# WPF Binding to method of a collection element

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, objectdataprovider

Im searching for the best practice (or any working solution) for the following scenario:

I have an `Employee` class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string DisplayName
    { get; set; }

    // It is important that this method has a parameter
    public string GetSomething(string param)
    { return param + DisplayName; }
}
```

I have a `List<Employee>` type object which is bound to a ComboBox in XAML.

The DisplayName for each employee is correctly showing in the ComboBox, but how can I show the return value of the GetSomething method **with an exact parameter for all employees** for each employee instead of the DisplayName?

**Binding to a method is OK, but how can I bind to multiple instances (for each employee object in the list)?** With the `ObjectDataProvider` I can only bind to one exact instance (or a class), not each employee object of the employee list.

Comment: If you like our answers, you should show it by giving them upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save yourself some trouble: use a view model and create a separate property that returns the value you want for each employee. To give a more detailed answer, I need to know where the parameter comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Kent Boogaart that using a view model is definitely the desired way to go (as well as a best practice).

Another possibility that I have used before (before I knew more about Model-View-ViewModel) is to use a [BindingConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx).  Bind either to your Employee class or to the DisplayName property and pass in the parameter as the parameter to the binding converter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The view model is definitely the way to go. Im just getting deeper into MVVM, and the situation was not clear for the first sight.